# Why is Android Studio not loading after successful installation?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I have installed Java JDK for Android and after successful installation of 
the Android Studio bundle I wanted to start Android. The green box and yellow line all successfully appeared and after that I got

> Fetching Android component information

and after that

> Downloading SDK components

dialogue box appears and nothing happens. The main screen of Android Studio is not appearing. I am stuck here. I tried again re-installing but no use.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please update screen shot for reference

Comment: I could not post the screen shot as it says that I should have 10 reputations.

Comment: Now add your screen shot

Comment: i changed the title too. Now screen shot uploaded.

Comment: when you start installing Android studio first time. it will start downloading SDK components and it will take time   to download all of them so cancel it and start Android studio.

Comment: It is accepting cancel button but dialogue box is not closing.  Again 
Android studio is not starting. I have to restart the system again. Only then
I could start Android and again it comes and hangs at this dialogue box.

Comment: wait to cancel it and when you will restart AS it will start normally after that you can open SDK manager and download components from there.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the process stopped responding, looking at your picture it just looks like it actually is downloading.

The Android SDK is at least over 100MB, and depending on which addons and libraries you add, the download can easily double or triple that, and take a long time to finish.

I believe you should just let it keep on downloading until it's completed, as it needs to do it once before the IDE will open for the first time.

Comment: I think in the AS bundle some main SDK folders are included. Wont that help to open the screen. Previously whent I installed I didnt face this problem.